# Multiple three condition statement for determining printing cost

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am doing a printing cost project and it has three conditions to output the right price value. The conditions being the Size of paper, Colour or B&W (black and white) and Single/Double sided.

```
For example
 IF Size=8.5x11"  Color/B&W= B&W   Sided= Single  **result= 0.1** 
 IF Size=8.5x11"  Color/B&W= Color Sided= Double  **result= 0.4**
 IF Size=11x17"   Color/B&W= B&W   Sided= Single  **result= 0.25**
```

and so on, therefore I am not sure how to combine the three conditions into 1 big  statement. I have attached the picture of the spreadsheet which has the rates written out.[image]

Comment: Are the only conditions the ones you've shown in the photo above (total of 8)?

Comment: Also, do you have a separate entry/selection in each column, per row, for each of the three possible choices (i.e.: 'Side Cts.', 'Size Choice', 'Colour Choice' for each row?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AND` function along with nested `IF`s. I assume you just want a formula here, not VBA

```
=IF(AND(A2="Single sided", B2="B&W", C1="8.5x11"), 0.1, IF(AND(A2="Single sided", B2="B&W", D1="11x17"), 0.25, IF(AND(A2="Single sided", B3="Colour", C1="8.5x11"), 0.25, 0.9)))
```

Notice I am making some assumptions as to cell references. Hopefully you see the pattern I'm using. There may be a way that requires less typing, but this felt intuitive to me.